# Rails: Unsupported: TrueClass Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting an error I have never seen before `unsupported: TrueClass` when I try to view my `users#show` page.  I have a basic to do app with `lists` and `items`. I had this code and it was working just fine:

```
    <% if @lists.count != 1 %>
      <li><%= @lists.count %> Personal Lists</li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= @lists.count %> Personal List</li>
    <% end %>

    <% if @shared_lists.count != 1 %>
      <li><%= @shared_lists.count %> Shared Lists</li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= @shared_lists.count %> Shared List</li>
    <% end %>

    <% if @items_delegated_to.count != 1 %>
      <li><%= @items_delegated_to.count %> Tasks Delegated to Me</li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= @items_delegated_to.count %> Task Delegated to Me</li>
    <% end %>
```

But when I added this block the error appeared:

```
    <% if @items_delegated_by.count != 1 %>  ***ERROR CALLED ON THIS LINE***
      <li><%= @items_delegated_by.count %> Tasks Delegated to Others</li>
    <% else %>
      <li><%= @items_delegated_by.count %> Task Delegated to Others</li>
    <% end %>
```

Here is my `users_controller`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @lists = current_user.lists
    @items = current_user.items
    @shared_lists = @lists.where(:shared_with == current_user.id)
    @items_delegated_by = @items.where(:delegated_to != "")
    @items_delegated_to = @items.where(:delegated_to == current_user.email)
  end
end
```

This is mysterious because it really isn't very different from the code preceeding it that worked without issue.  Can anyone explain a what an unsupported `TrueClass` is or why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your query to this:

```
 @items_delegated_by = @items.where.not(delegated_to: "")
```

Comment: The first one worked like a charm, but the second one actually made it yield `0` when it was previously reading `2` (the correct value).

Comment: Ok if you're sure that it should be 2, then leave it like this !

Comment: Thanks for the help!